# You can't see the content ofthis report because you don't have permissions to the underlyingdataset?

Tags: powerbi, row-level-security

i have implement dynamic RLS in one of my report using USERPRINCIPALNAME(). i have created one table(UserDetail) which is filtering my main table and the userdetails which useremail have access to which client

[image]

[image]

after this i deployed this to service but when i try to access this with other account

it gives me this error

[image]

Any suggestion how i can fix this error (Note: i have given my other account viewer access in workspace)

Answer (score 0):

Create a report that will be used just for troubleshooting. Do not set up RLS. For data, you only need whatever is feeding the [User Email] measure. Use cards to display the results of [UserEmail] and USERPRINCIPALNAME(). Make sure the values of those are what you think they are.

Be sure to look at the troubleshooting report in the Power BI Service, not just Desktop. If you work for a company with a federated Active Directory setup, the values of USERPRINCIPALNAME() can be different in Desktop where you may be connected via VPN versus in service when you're logged in to O365.

If you have this scenario where UPN is different depending on how the user is connected (or sometimes what subsidiary company they're coming from), I strongly encourage you to spend time building a permanant RLS troubleshooting report that you can direct users to visit and send you a screenshot of so that you can diagnose their issues. I know there is a View As feature in Power BI, but if you have to support a large user base, this report will save you a ton of time.

Another tip is rather than putting the RLS logic in the Table filter DAX expression field on the Manage Roles form as you have here (and as all the documentation instructs you to do), instead create a measure with that logic which simply returns boolean TRUE or FALSE and put that measure into the DAX expression field. It will save you a lot of clicks if you're having to tweak it some thing that works.